# Global minima of multivariate constrained linear function

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

I have a function of form
$ax+by+cz$ where $a$, $b$, $c$ are real numbers.
Also $x, y, z$ are greater than equal to $0$ and
$x+y+z$ less than equal to $C$ (a constant). What's the global minimum of this function ($ax+by+cz$)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear functional on the convex set $C= \operatorname{co} \{0, Ce_1, C e_2, C e_3 \}$. The extrema will occur at an extreme point, hence the global minimum is $\min (0, aC ,bC,cC)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't understand how to arrive at this result. Can you quote some reference if you have? Thanks

Comment: I don't have a specific reference, but it is not too hard to show that  if $C= \operatorname{co} \{ x_1,....,x_p\}$ then if $l$ is linear, we have $\max_{x \in C} l(x) = \max_k l(x_k)$.